# Inverse Laplace Transform, need help with this $\frac{s^2}{s^2+\sqrt{2}s+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{s^2}{s^2+\sqrt{2}s+1}$

I transformed the denominator as $(s+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^{2}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{s^2}{(s+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}}$ and I have no idea how to move forward because partial fraction decomposition fails.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{s^2}{s^2+\sqrt2\,s+1}=1-\frac{\sqrt2\left(s+\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)}{\left(s+\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2+\frac12}$$

Comment: how you got this? :)

Comment: In the numerator, write $s^2=s^2+\sqrt2\,s+1-\sqrt2\,s-1$

Comment: @EM4 I think he/she made the long division.

Comment: I lost again how did that happen 1 - $\sqrt{2}$ (s + $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)

Comment: @EM4  Use the inverse laplace transform of cosine function and the first shifting theore. Here you have that $c=-\dfrac {\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: I solved it, thanks to everyone for the help. 

now this problem has become my favorite so far HAHAH,

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=s+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$:
$$\dfrac{s^2}{(s+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{(u-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2}{u^{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}}$$
Then  expand...And apply the first Shifting Theorem.

$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\dfrac {\left(s+\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)}{{\left(s+\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2+\frac12}}=e^{-\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}t}\cos \left(\dfrac {\sqrt 2}{2}t \right)$$